# CUrl cookies stored in local but not on remote

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I've made a simple `PHP browser` to navigate on remote websites. It works perfectly when I run the script on my local server (It stores cookies and I can retrieve a session later using the `sid`). But when I push my files to my remote server, it doesn't save the cookies. It looks to create a new session everytime.

Did I make something wrong or do I have to enable a special option on my remote server ?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Browser
{
  private $session_id = '';
  private $user_agent = '';
  private $curl = null;

  function __construct($session_id, $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2')
  {
    $this->session_id = $session_id;
    $this->user_agent = $user_agent;

    // Create a new instance of Curl
    $this->curl = curl_init();
    if (empty($this->curl)) throw new Exception('CURL doesn\'t look to be available');
  }

  function __destruct()
  {
    // Close session
    curl_close($this->curl);
    unset($this->curl);
  }

  private function request($url, $reset_cookies, $post_data)
  {    
    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL               => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1,
      CURLOPT_HEADER            => 0,
      CURLOPT_FAILONERROR       => 1,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT         => $this->user_agent,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT    => 30,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => 0,   
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    => 1,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS         => 10,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER       => 1,
      CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION     => $reset_cookies ? 1 : 0,
      CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR         => $this->session_id,
      CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE        => $this->session_id,
    );

    // Add POST data
    if (isset($post_data))
    {
      $options[CURLOPT_POST]          = 1;
      $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]    = http_build_query($post_data);
    }

    // Attach options
    curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $options);

    // Execute the request and read the response
    $content = curl_exec($this->curl);

    // Handle any error
    if (curl_errno($this->curl)) throw new Exception(curl_error($this->curl));

    return $content;
  }

  public function get($url, $reset_cookies = false)
  {
    return $this->request($url, $reset_cookies, null);
  }

  public function post($url, $post_data, $reset_cookies = false)
  {
    return $this->request($url, $reset_cookies, $post_data);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would be checking that the remote server allows you to write files to wherever curl writes its cookie data to.

Comment: Also if it is shared hosting, you may need to see if the php.ini is setup the same as yours regarding curl. But it does sound like a permissions issue.

Comment: Can I force the location where the cookies are stored ?

Comment: You can provide an absolute path to where you want them stored in your settings.. ie.. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/cookies/" . $this->session_id`

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head if `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` has a slash at the end so you may need to toy around with this.

Comment: I got that kind of path `/var/www/sites/mywebsite/public_html/cookies/ffffffffebb0d92d1d45421b3f433a4c1394880449964`

Comment: But the file isn't created automatically by `CUrl`. Do I need to create it manually ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49804/discussion-between-michael-coxon-and-manitoba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your cookies folder is outside of the `public_html` folder and that the user that is running PHP has access to write to the folder.

Set the folder permissions to `755`, this will be enough. Any extra permissions are a security hole and can let other people write to the folder on shared hosting..

example path...

`/home/my_awesome_website/cookies`